# Expose SQL Results as REST API

Tags: java, oracle, api, rest

Is there a way to expose SQL results as REST API?

I have Oracle DB and the requirement is, if I write a sql, the results should be exposed via REST api.

Thank you

Comment: You should try doing it, and post any coding challenges here, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Oracle REST Data Services (ORDS). It's free.

- https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/rest.html

Comment: Thank you. This says changes have to be done at Oracle DB level in order to expose the results. Is there a way to achieve the same thing without any changes to DB?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but it would involve an external programming language and application tier in your technology stack, and likely wouldn't perform as well or be as well integrated with the DB. ORDS allows you to REST enable tables, views, etc. without necessarily writing a single line of code.